Is the lateral edge of a prism a straight line or a segment?
Is the lateral edge of a prism a straight line or a segment?
Let AB be the lateral edge of a prism...If we let a point X on the lateral edge AB, then $X\in [AB]$ or it can also be outside of it? I need it to solve a problem. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

It's not clear what you mean.  What is the difference between $AB$ and $[AB]$ in your notation?

@RobertIsrael AB is a line while [AB] is a segment

How is it outside? Like on the continuation of AB? How does two faces remain parallel then

@Gwen Yes, this is what i mean...on its continuation

@Gwen i posted the full problem on my secondary account AdelinaPopescu

You have not posted the problem statement, so this is just a direct answer:

Is the lateral edge of a prism a straight line or a segment?

The "edge" or "side" of a figure is a segment: it is <<part of a straight line that is bounded by two distinct end points>>, the two points here being two adjacent vertices of the figure.

If we let a point $X$ on the lateral edge $AB$, then $X \in [AB]$ or it can also be outside of it?

The notation should be made clear in context: anyway, if the problem statement asks for "a point on an edge", that is a point on the segment, not outside of it.

When we say only a prism its extrusion length is unspecified. For a truncated prism one specifies the length or height of the prism.
The edge can be a straight line of infinite length or a portion of it as a segment depending on what you specify as required.
For a polygon section e.g., the extruded segment length is an intersection of adjacent surfaces and always lies on the prism when outer surface slopes suddenly change.
The prisms below have finite edge lengths by which its base sections are pulled up to generate/sweep laral surfaces:

